# Shell echo to file ending up on multiple lines?

Tags: shell, unix

What I'm doing is: `echo put $clientfilepath'client-'$clientversion-'.jar' >> ftp.ftp` in a shell file.
Where `$clientfilepath` is: `c:\\workspace\\project\\jack\\prj1\\target\\` and `$clientversion` is `1.0-snapshot`

What I expect in ftp.ftp:

```
put
c:\\workspace\\project\\jack\\prj1\\target\\client-1.0-snapshot.jar
```

But what I'm getting is:

```
put c:\\workspace\\project\\jack\\prj1\\target\\
client-1.0-snapshot 
.jar
```

I'm using double \ so nothing in the filepath should get treated as a special character.
So does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: It seems that $clientfilepath ends with a space?

Comment: @cebewee, it was not input correctly; I fixed the formatting, it'll be easier to see the problem now :)

Comment: @Jack, how was `$clientfilepath` generated? I'd guess it has an extra `'\n'` character at the end.

Comment: It's read from a property file, and no it doesn't have a \n at the end of it. I echoed the value to be certain.

Comment: This really looks like there is a newline at the end. Try using `printf "%s" $clientfilepath | hd` and look for a trailing "0a" in the output.

Comment: @cebewee: rather, `printf %s "$clientfilepath" | hd`

Comment: Says hd is not know, but doing printf "%s" $clientfilepath >> ftp.ftp does not show a blank line beneath the filepath

Comment: You need to try Roman's variant, i got the quotes wrong

Comment: Still command not found.

Comment: Use `hexdump -C` instead of `hd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   echo put $clientfilepath'client-'$clientversion-'.jar'|tr '\n' '' >> ftp.ftp
```

Comment: It still gers split up. It's really quite strange.

Comment: This would have to be `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: Even with -d it gets split up

Comment: I needed to do it where the variables were set but that's the sollution

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the quoting:

```
echo "put ${clientfilepath}client-${clientversion}-.jar" >> ftp.ftp
```

Try that to see if it helps with your problem. Also try `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
printf 'put %sclient-%s-.jar\n' "$clientfilepath" "$clientversion" >> ftp.ftp
```

Comment: Both end up like in my original situation

Comment: @Jack: Do you see newlines if you pipe it through `hexdump -C`?